# ActionMailer Observer not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, observer-pattern

I defined an ActionMailer Observer and it's not being called. How can I go about troubleshooting this?  Rails 3.1.3, Ruby 1.9.2.  Alternatively, I want a method called whenever an email is sent form a certain ActionMailer subclass.  This is the only clean way I could find to implement this (I could call a method from each mailing method in the ActionMailer subclass, but that's not very DRY).  Any other suggestions as to how to accomplish this would be welcome.

```
config/initializers/mail_observer.rb:
  class MailObserver
    def self.delivered_email(message)
      require 'ruby-debug' ; debugger
      user = User.find_by_email(message.to[0])
      if user
        email_type = caller[1]
        UserMailerLogging.create!(user_id: @user.id, email_type: email_type, contents: self.body)
      end
    end
  end

  ActionMailer::Base.register_observer(MailObserver)

app/mailers/user_mailer:
  class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: "no-reply@testing.com"
    ...
    def unfinished_setup(user)
      @user = user
      mail to: user_email(user), subject: "Testing..."
    end
    ...
  end
```

And, in the Rails Console:

```
irb(main):001:0> UserMailer.unfinished_setup(User.find(1))    
=> #<Mail::Message:70192154395900, Multipart: false, Headers: <From: no-reply@testing.com>, <To: Test User<user@testing.com>>, <Subject: Testing...>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: text/plain>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the observer won't fire until you actually deliver the message. Your code in the rails console is only creating the email, not sending it. Adding `.deliver` to the end should deliver the message and execute the observer code.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. My production code had the deliver in it (the caller to the mailer), but I didn't append `.deliver` to the test command in the console. Doing so resolved the issue.